# Functors of tilting modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $G$ be a reductive group over $k$. Inside the category $Rep_k(G)$ of $k$-linear representations of $G$, there's the subcategory $Tilt_k(G)$ of tilting modules.

Suppose I have a symmetric monoidal functor $Tilt(G) \rightarrow Tilt(H)$ compatible with the fiber functor. Does it necessarily extend to a functor of Tannakian categories $Rep(G) \rightarrow Rep(H)$? (Equivalently, need it be induced by a homomorphism $H \rightarrow G$?) If not, are there simple additional conditions that would guarantee this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If G is semisimple and simply connected and the functor is faithful, then Theorem 3.3.1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.04303.pdf says the answer is yes.  They show that any faithful symmetric tensor functor from $Tilt(G)$ to an abelian symmetric tensor category extends to an exact functor on all of $Rep(G)$.  We say that $Rep(G)$ is the *abelian envelope* of $Tilt(G)$ when this happens.

I'd guess that the semisimple simply connected assumption can probably be relaxed to connected reductive with a bit more work, but I haven't thought about it carefully.

Comment: Thanks! Faithful follows my assumption on compatibility with fiber functors, so that's ok. Would be really happy to see the extension to connected reductive groups.

Comment: The extension (and generalization) to the case of connected reductive groups is Proposition 7.3.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.00094.pdf Also Proposition 7.3.2 implies that compatibility with fiber functor guarantees faithfulness of the functor.

Comment: Thanks! I don't need 7.3.2 for faithfulness though do I? Isn't it clear from the faithfulness of the fiber functor?

Comment: @user333154: yes, you are right! Faithfulness is easy and 7.3.2 is not needed.